# Wait for loading of factory before resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have code like this:

```
meow.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/page', {
        templateUrl: 'application/partials/page.html',
        controller: 'index',
        resolve: {'page': ['$resolve', function($resolve) {return $resolve.page();}]}
    })
    .when('/page2', {
        templateUrl: 'application/partials/page2.html',
        controller: 'index',
        resolve: {'page2': ['$resolve', function($resolve) {return $resolve.page2();}]}
    })
    ...
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/error'
    });
}]);
meow.factory('$resolve', ['$q', '$user', function($q, $user) {
    return {
        page: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            if ($user.logged()) {
                $http.get('/json/page')
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve();
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.reject();
                });
            } else {
                deferred.reject();
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        }
        page2:...
        page3:...
        ...
    }
}]);
```

As you can see there is check of user access in `$resolve` factory: `$user.logged()`, but `$user` is async and on first load it cause problems with access.

The question is how to make all my resolves wait for `$user`?
I have $user.q() function which giving promise, but how to inject it to my code for all resolves? Or maybe some other solution with `$routeChangeStart` or `$locationChangeStart` events? Or should I just insert `$user.q().then(...)` in every resolve?

**Update 1:**
My user code:

```
meow.factory('$user', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http) {
    var id = null;
    var accesslevel = 0;

    function update() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('/json/user')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data.logged) {
                id = data.id;
                accesslevel = data.accesslevel;
            } else {
                id = null;
                accesslevel = 0;
            }
            deferred.resolve();
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject();
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    var q = update();

    return {
        logged: function() { return (id) ? true : false; },
        id: function() { return id; },
        accesslevel: function() { return accesslevel; },
        reset: function() {
            id = null;
            accesslevel = 0;
        },
        update: function() { return q = update(); },

        q: function() { return q; }
    };
}]);
```

Not controller should wait for `$user.q()`, resolve should. When I tryed to make it as additional resolve in `$routeProvider`, `page` resolve trying to load `/json/page`, but should not until `$user.q()` resolved and `$user.logged() = true`.

So the only way is to add

```
    page: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $user.q().then(function() {
            if ($user.logged()) {
                $http.get('/json/page')
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve();
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.reject();
                });
            } else {
                deferred.reject();
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

to each resolve?

Comment: Once something is async you cannot make it blocking without causing UI issues, as would would block the entire app from doing anything.
Can you change $user to return a promise instead?

Comment: @Enzey, Did you read last part of my question?

Comment: @ShamilYakupov, how is this `$resolve` service going to be used. And have you looked into `resolve` property of [`$routeProvider.when`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#when)?

Comment: Ok, got it... So, why can't you do the check inside `$user.load().then(function(){ if ($user.logged() { ... } })`? Make sure that `$user.load` caches the promise so you wont' have to query the server every time

Comment: @ShamilYakupov, yes - one way is to add this to each page resolver. the other - is as suggested by @brianvaughn in answer below - inject a resolved user into the page resolver function. `resolve` allows to use other `resolve` variables as injected dependencies. And, off-topic, don't use `q.defer` - this is anti-pattern when you already have an API that returns a promise - `$http` in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you would normally approach dependencies like this would be to make `user` its own resolve and then make other resolve(s) depend on it, like so:

```
resolve: {
  user: function($user) {
    return $user.q();
  },
  somethingElse: function(user, $otherService) {
    // Whatever else
  }
}
```

This is *kind of* covered in [UI Router wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve).

Answer (score 0):

$user itself could be a promise that resolve to all service methods or you could resolve each service individually.

Usage

```
$user.then(function(userService) {
    userService.logged();
});
```

Resolution

```
var userDeferred= $q.defer();
userDeferred.resolve({
    logged: function() {
        return false;
    }
});
return userDeferred.promise;
```